# Kendo AutoComplete Creating two Times

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I tried to create Kendo Autocomplete. I'm initialising Autocomplete where ever it's required using Id. when ever initialising it's creating two times.

Please have look my dojo link http://dojo.telerik.com/eqoqU

FYI, This dojo example for sample. If it's resolve it here then i can resolve in my actual code also.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: why you initializing it two times `$("#autocomplete").kendoAutoComplete`?

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar - I just created for sample Dojo. Actual code is different. is it possible to resolve?

Comment: In your original code you call `$("#autocomplete").kendoAutoComplete` only once?